# What does STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE do?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand an open source implementation of a SAT solver (miniSAT http://minisat.se/downloads/MiniSat_v1.12b_src.zip) . In one of the header files I came across the following code snippet.

```
template <bool> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE;
template <> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true>{};
#define TEMPLATE_FAIL STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>()
```

I am unable to understand what this does exactly. From what I understood about templates, they usually have the format

```
template <class T>
```

But after looking up a few things online, I found that templates can be used to make compile time executions by using

```
template <datatype>
```

In this case the data type is bool. But I am unable to fully appreciate what such a code does. I am especially confused with the second and third line.

Further ahead in the code, TEMPLATE_FAIL is used in the method of a generic class as follows :-

```
// Don't allow copying (error prone):
vec<T>&  operator = (vec<T>& other) { TEMPLATE_FAIL; }
         vec        (vec<T>& other) { TEMPLATE_FAIL; }
```

This particular code snippet seems to be part of some libraries to check for assert failures. But then again, I am unable to fully appreciate this in terms of templates,  constructors etc. (Please, give suggestions on how I could improve the question format , if it lacks something.)

Thank You.

Comment: MSalter's answer covers most of your questions. Regarding `TEMPLATE_FAIL` - it tries to create a temporary of the declared but undefined (i.e. *incomplete*) type, resulting in a compilation error: basically communicating "it was a mistake to try to use this function". It works inside another template because a template's member functions aren't fully compiled unless there's an attempt to call them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a specialized template. The base template `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<bool>` is not defined, but the specialization `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE` is defined. As a result, `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<expr>` is defined **if and only if** `expr` is a compile-time constant `true`.

Practically speaking, this means that `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<(2+2==4)>` is defined but `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<(2+2==5)>` is not. The latter is therefore a link error.

C++11 introduces `static_assert<>` for this purpose. It tends to give clearer error messages

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not quite right since `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<(2+2==4)>` is the same just saying `vector<int>` - i.e. it wont compile. `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<(2+2==4)>();` might though. And will actually be a compile time error for `2+2==5`

Comment: Interesting. So here is how I understand templates when used as generic class. The Class T is like  a placeholder for whatever class one wants to use the generic class with. Now in this case instead of the class we have <bool> . So here's my understanding. We have to define for all the possible values of bool . And here purposefully STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false> is not given a definition ?

Comment: I am looking at an older piece of source-code to better understand it. So it is definitely pre C++ - 11

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: True, you can't use a type simply by adding a semicolon. That doesn't make a valid statement. However, you can add `();` to default-create it assuming you're in a scope where expressions are allowed.

Comment: @ameyask86: Not defining `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>` is intentional. See edit.

Comment: A few C++ concepts which I wish to understand here. `template<class T>` allows one to define a generic class or a function. So what exactly is `template <bool> struct` doing here - is it a generic type? And in particular what is `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true>` , and why do we have a `template <> struct` preceding it.

Comment: @ameyask86: Right, it seems you're unfamiliar with non-type template arguments. `class T` is a type template argument, but you can also have integral constants. E.g. `std:array` has two template arguments. The first one is the element type, the second is the element count: `std::array<int,20>`.

Answer (score 2):

`template <bool> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE;` declares a template class which takes a single boolean template argument.

`template <> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true>{};` is a *specialization* of `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE` for when the template argument passed is true.

Understanding what this is for is best with an example.

Say we have a type trait which checks if a type is a pointer, like `std::is_pointer` from the `type_traits` header:

```
std::is_pointer<int>::value == false
std::is_pointer<int*>::value == true
```

Now we can try to instantiate our `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE` struct using these:

```
STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<std::is_pointer<int>::value>
//same as
STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false> //an incomplete type

STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<std::is_pointer<int*>::value>
//same as
STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true> //a valid, complete type
```

Now you can see that if we use those `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE` instantiations in some valid context, we'll get a translation error when we attempt to use anything that maps to `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>`.